# Nginx (1.11.x)New Mainline release Installation on Amazon Linux

Tags: nginx

`enter code here`I need to install **nginx latest mainline release 1.11.x** on **amazon linux** running on ec2 instance.

I followed the below link of nginx official documentation to install the same, the steps are very clear but still i couldnt install on amazon linux.
I tried the same on RHEL 7 on ec2 which is perfectly working fine with the steps given in the link but not on amazon linux, Below is the link which i referred to do the installation process

https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/installing-nginx-open-source/

Is it Amazon linux is not yet compatible with the nginx newer release??? i could install 1.8.x version of nginx in aws linux without issues which is already found in amazon repository.
I tried accessing the nginx repository and install the specific version but i got error, Below is the error which i got

```
yum install nginx
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nginx.x86_64 1:1.11.2-1.el7.ngx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: 1:nginx-1.11.2-     1.el7.ngx.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:nginx-1.11.2-1.el7.ngx.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:nginx-1.11.2-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
       Requires: systemd
Error: Package: 1:nginx-1.11.2-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
       Requires: libpcre.so.1()(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
led by skipping the same
```